# How to install older version of Laravel (5.7) using newest composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have currently installed the latest version of composer and laravel (6) . I inherited an older project running on 5.. I want to get a laravel framework up and running at 5.7 so I can run the old project. I tried :

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel  "5.7.*"

I keep getting the error: mkdir(): Permission denied.

I'm running this on Windows 10 gitbash and it doesn't recognize sudo.

I've also tried : composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.7.*"  
and I also get the same error

Would appreciate the help :)

Comment: Please share more details. I don't think that the given error message is related to either Composer or Laravel - as it states, there is a more broad permission issue

Comment: Have you tried running terminal on Run as administrator?

Comment: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourProjectName "5.7.*" , this must work! 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7

Comment: It's clearly a filesystem issue. Are you sure the user you're logged in as has permissions to create directories on that path?

Comment: Yes it was a filesystem permissions issue as it turns out . Thanks guys .  Found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQD-hnMgfBM While it's a shotgun approach it works

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:5.7.* "Your_project_name"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. How does this solve the permission issue?